# Are Oral Pleasures Considered An Act Of Zina if not married?

Tags: zina, relationships

If so, what are not acts of zina that I could preform to pleasure the one I'm marrying?

Comment: Please attempt your own research before asking, as this query is extremely basic. You may not perform *any* act of pleasure with someone you are not married to. Oral acts would be a form of Zina, but are not the form for which there is a prescribed punishment (Hadd) in Islamic law, rather it would carry a Tazir.

Comment: So basically that's not allowed... Nor is any kind of pleasure. If I do so I will get sent to the deepest pits of hell. Correct?

Comment: @QuestionIneed wrong we can't say what will happen to you in the hereafter as you may still do many deeds doing a misdeed and repenting from it is as if you've never commit it (if the repentance was sincere)

Comment: You shouldn't edit your questions in order to ask a completely new question.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are not married you are not even allowed to be alone with a foreign person (which your to be spouse is).
Both of you are not allowed to talk about such subjects at all.
In the time before marriage the fiancées  can only meet in company of a mahram of the future wife (or in public). The talk between them should be of a kind to learn to know each other to be able to decide whether or not they should go further in this engagement however the to be husband is allowed to see a bit more of his to be wife (of course not in public) as the appearance may play a part for the above decision. Intimate talk that leads to arausal doesn't fit to this.

So the answer is there's nothing that you may be allowed to do before you get legally married.
But if you for whatever reason had any kind of intimacy or pleasure before marriage this is counted as zina or a form of zina even if only zina with a penetration has prescribed punishment in the shari'a.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up! I just wanted to know.